# Getting counts of data in R

Tags: r

I am using R for the first time.  I have the following data set ( a mockup of a very large data set that I am actually working with):

```
Type       Date         Size       Color
L shape    2008-04-14   161    blue    
L shape    2010-10-16   654    yellow
L shape    2005-07-03   149    blue
L shape    2006-08-16   657    yellow
L shape    2007-04-08   229    yellow
L shape    2004-03-17   784    green
Y shape    2014-02-22   917    pink
Y shape    2012-05-04   186    green
Y shape    2006-11-25   641    yellow
Y shape    2015-09-07   493    blue
Y shape 2011-07-06  953 green
```

I would like to get back the number of occurrances of each Color for each Type, the Dates for each Type and the min, max and mean for the Size for each type.  Output should look like this:

```
Type       Colors   Dates           Mean Size   Min Size    Max Size
L shape      3          2008-04-14  439         149         784
                2010-10-16          
                2005-07-03          
                2006-08-16          
                2007-04-08          
                2004-03-17          

Y shape     4           2014-02-22  638         186         953
                2012-05-04          
                2006-11-25          
                2015-09-07          
                2011-07-06
```

This is what I’ve done so far:

```
cat <- big_catalog

na.rm = TRUE

library(plyr)

mydata <-ddply(cat, c("Type", "Date", "Size", "Color"), summarize,
               Colors = length(Color),
               Dates = (Date),
               Mean_Size = mean(Size),
               Minimum_Size = min(Size),
               Maximum_Size = max(Size)
)
```

But I end up with this:

```
Type    Date    Size    Color   Colors  Dates   Mean Size   Min Size    Max Size
L shape 2008-04-14  161 blue    2   2008-04-14  161 161 161
L shape 2010-10-16  654 yellow  3   2010-10-16  654 654 654
L shape 2005-07-03  149 blue    2   2005-07-03  149 149 149
L shape 2006-08-16  657 yellow  3   2006-08-16  657 657 657
L shape 2007-04-08  229 yellow  2   2007-04-08  229 229 229
L shape 2004-03-17  784 green   1   2004-03-17  784 784 784
Y shape 2014-02-22  917 pink    1   2014-02-22  917 917 917
Y shape 2012-05-04  186 green   2   2012-05-04  186 186 186
Y shape 2006-11-25  641 yellow  1   2006-11-25  641 641 641
Y shape 2015-09-07  493 blue    1   2015-09-07  493 493 493
Y shape 2011-07-06  953 green   2   2011-07-06  953 953 953
```

I apparently need to loop over this, but I am very new to R and I don’t see how to do it.

Comment: Don't group by every column, just group by the `Type` column. (Since you want everything done "for each type".) Though your request for `Date` to be multi-row where everything else is single-row complicates matters...

Answer (score 0):

something like....

```
df <- read.table(text=
"Type       Date         Size       Color
Lshape    2008-04-14   161    blue    
Lshape    2010-10-16   654    yellow
Lshape    2005-07-03   149    blue
Lshape    2006-08-16   657    yellow
Lshape    2007-04-08   229    yellow
Lshape    2004-03-17   784    green
Yshape    2014-02-22   917    pink
Yshape    2012-05-04   186    green
Yshape    2006-11-25   641    yellow
Yshape    2015-09-07   493    blue
Yshape 2011-07-06  953 green", header=TRUE)

by(df, df$Type, function(x){
  data.frame(Colors = length(unique(x$Color)),
             Dates = paste(x$Date, collapse=";"),
             Mean.size = mean(x$Size),
             Min.size = min(x$Size),
             Max.size = max(x$Size))
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helps.